# How to get Proof of Delivery Image via UPS API?

Tags: ups

I'm using ups API for tracking packages for many years now. Works fine.

Now I'm trying to get the Proof of Delivery image, but can't seem to find how to do this.

In the UPS PDF document there seems to be something called "Signature Tracking", but not a word on how to implement/call this signature tracking.

Up till now I called:

```
$"https://onlinetools.ups.com/api/track/v1/details/{TrackCode}"
```

What do I need to do to get the POD image?

Thanks